# Robolectric and external jar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parse-platform, robolectric

I'm trying to learn `Robolectric`. So i'm testing an application created on Eclipse.
The project uses `Parse-1.7.1.jar` to receive push notifications. I set up robolectric following these [instructions](http://robolectric.org/eclipse-quick-start/). However, when I try to run the test I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: In order to use the ParsePush.subscribe or ParsePush.unsubscribe methods you must add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml: 
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
  android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
(Replace "com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" with your own implementation if you choose to extend ParsePushBroadcastReceiver)
at com.parse.ParsePush.checkForManifestAndThrowExceptionIfNeeded(ParsePush.java:152)
at com.parse.ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(ParsePush.java:78)
at com.parse.ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(ParsePush.java:99)
at mx.com.ronda.test.RondaApplication.onCreate(RondaApplication.java:25)
at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:126)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:440)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:158)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

My android project is not declaring `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` on the manifest since i'm extending it. I tried adding Parse as an external jar to my testing java project(properties > java build path > libraries > add external jars), but it's not working.

Let me know if you need more info. I hope you could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the very same problem, so I created a TestApplication commenting the `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`, and it worked.

**Notice that you must put `Test` before your application name (Create a new class and copy-paste the original application).**

Like this:

```
public class TestMyMoneyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        //ParseCrashReporting.enable(getApplicationContext());
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "", "");
        //ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("");
    }
}
```

That's all you need to do.
Just to clarify, this is a workaround, I didn't find a solution to the problem!

Comment: OMG it worked! Thank you so much. One last thing, could you please tell me why that works, or point me to the documentation that explains that?

Comment: To be honest with you I don't know why the ParsePush doesn't work, I'm still digging into it. If I find something on that matter I'll edit my answer here and leave a comment !